# rabbitmq-priority-queue plugin install issue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, priority-queue, amqp

I tried to install [rabbitmq-priority-queue](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-priority-queue) on my ubuntu 12.04 machine which is running rabbitmq 3.4.0.

according to the instructions in http://www.rabbitmq.com/installing-plugins.html, I've copied the downloaded file rabbitmq_priority_queue-3.4.x-3431dc1e.ez to /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.4.0/plugins
and enabled the plugin via command:

```
$ sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_priority_queue
```

when running the example application in https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-priority-queue/blob/master/examples/java/src/com/rabbitmq/examples/PriorityQueue.java 
I got the following output:

```
Sent message with priority 0
Sent message with priority 5
Sent message with priority 10
Received message with priority 0
Received message with priority 5
Received message with priority 10
```

although I expect the output to be:

```
Sent message with priority 0
Sent message with priority 5
Sent message with priority 10
Received message with priority 10
Received message with priority 5
Received message with priority 0
```

which means, consume the highest priority message first.

I've tried to do the following (none worked):

- restarted rabbit
- disabled-enabled the plugin
- deleted the queue (so it would be recreated by the app)
- changed .ez file permissions to -rw-r--r-- (just like all other plugins)

I've noticed that when I'm enabling the plugin I get the following output:

```
$ sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_priority_queue
The following plugins have been enabled:
  rabbitmq_priority_queue

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@<my laptop name>...WARNING: module rabbit_priority_queue not found, so not scanned for boot steps.
WARNING: module rabbit_priority_queue not found, so not scanned for boot steps.
 started 1 plugin.
```

But when running 'sudo rabbitmq-plugins list' I get:

```
$ sudo rabbitmq-plugins list
 Configured: E = explicitly enabled; e = implicitly enabled
 | Status:   * = running on rabbit@benny-laptop
 |/
[e*] amqp_client                       3.4.0
[  ] cowboy                            0.5.0-rmq3.4.0-git4b93c2d
[  ] eldap                             3.4.0-gite309de4
[e*] mochiweb                          2.7.0-rmq3.4.0-git680dba8
[  ] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_federation               3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.4.0
[E*] rabbitmq_management               3.4.0
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_management_visualiser    3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.4.0
[E*] rabbitmq_priority_queue           3.4.x-3431dc1e
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_test                     3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.4.0
[e*] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.4.0
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.4.0
[  ] sockjs                            0.3.4-rmq3.4.0-git3132eb9
[e*] webmachine                        1.10.3-rmq3.4.0-gite9359c7
```

According to the result [E*] it looks like the plugin is enabled.
I'm not sure if the plugin was enabled properly, or maybe I don't understand it correctly. Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah. Yes. That "module not found" error message is misleading. The binary version of the priority queue plugin that's available on the website is compiled with Erlang R15B - but the version of Erlang that ships with your Ubuntu is R14B04. So I think that's the root of the problem.

You could upgrade Erlang (Erlang Solutions offer backports of R16B for 12.04 from [here](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp)) or compile the plugin yourself (not for the faint hearted).

Meanwhile I'll look at getting the error message to say something more intelligent.